# how do I printf a long? Shouldn't this work? %li

Tags: c, printf

I read the documentation and it says that a long is %li but the print out comes back as -2147024891. What gives?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You didn't even provide which number you wanted to print, but I guess you've stumbled over the difference between signed and unsigned printing.

Use `%lu` for `unsigned long` numbers, and `%ld` or `%li` for `signed long` numbers.

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx) has good documentation on printf specifiers. For 64-bit values (like `long long`, for example), you should use the macros in [`<inttypes.h>`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/inttypes.h.html).

Answer (score 9):

You are trying to print an HRESULT, the error code for "access denied".  That is best formatted in hex, at least to be easily recognizable to a programmer and the Google query box.

```
printf("0x%08lx", hr);
```

Now you'll instantly recognize the facility code 7 (Windows API) and the error code 5 (access denied).

Comment: +1 For the nice observation. I'd point out though that an HRESULT is always 32-bits. The pendantician (can I say this word?) in me wants to point out that you should always use the fixed width macros for... well... fixed width integers, i.e. `printf("0x%08"PRIx32, hr);` in this case. The fact that Microsoft seems to not care about C99 is a side issue that I'd care not to acknowledge as relevant ;)

Comment: The OP is correct, HRESULT is typedef-ed to LONG.  Using %lx is not wrong.

Comment: You're right. It's typedef-ed to LONG, but LONG is specifically defined as, "32-bit signed integer. The range is –2147483648 through 2147483647 decimal."

Comment: This is the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you printing a unsigned value as signed? With two's complement, a value with the most significant bit set will be printed as a negative. Try %u for unsigned

Comment: "%u" is for the `unsigned int` type. The OP asked for printing `long` numbers.

Answer (score 0):

%ld or %lu  depending on the 'long' you need.

Answer (score 0):

Given the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    long l1 = +2147024891;
    long l2 = -2147024891;
    printf("%+11li = 0x%lx\n", l1, l1);
    printf("%+11li = 0x%lx\n", l2, l2);
    return(0);
}
```

The output compiled in 32-bit mode (on MacOS 10.6.2) is:

```
+2147024891 = 0x7ff8fffb
-2147024891 = 0x80070005
```

The output compiled in 64-bit mode is:

```
 2147024891 = 0x7ff8fffb
-2147024891 = 0xffffffff80070005
```

Since you don't show us what you wrote and why you expected something different, it is hard to say what could be wrong.  However, although relatively unusual, the '`%li`' conversion was in C89 as well as C99, so that should be correct.  The more normal conversion specifiers are '`%ld`' (a synonym of '`%li`') and '`%lu`' (and '`%lo`' and '`%lx`') for unsigned values.

Answer (score 0):

Try `%llu` and also for assigning a value to a long variable don't forget you must add `LL` in the end of the number, for instance `a = 999999999LL`.